# Google Wallet app api / created passes lead to error

Tags: node.js, android-pay, google-pay

I was following the tutorial
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-web for building a generic pass over the api.
using https://github.com/google-pay/wallet-web-codelab as repo.

after some struggling with the 7 days test account (if someone gets 403 unauthorized requests check that you use the same **iam** email for the test account on the register page)

okay, all works well, i get the stored wallet object back but when i try to reach the URL
[Test-URL with JWT](https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ3YWxsZXQtY29kZWxhYkBhbGRpLTM1MDQwOS5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6Imdvb2dsZSIsIm9yaWdpbnMiOlsiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwL2dvb2dsZSJdLCJ0eXAiOiJzYXZldG93YWxsZXQiLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImdlbmVyaWNPYmplY3RzIjpbeyJpZCI6IjMzODgwMDAwMDAwMjIxMjIyMzIuY2hyaXM4N19oZW5zY2hlbHMubmV0LTI4YWJiOTA3LTExZDItNGFjOS1hNDFjLTkxNmExYTUyZDVmOCJ9XX0sImlhdCI6MTY1Mjg1NzQzOX0.SllmP2wYIyq3W1bY7_sEKh0NuoNBcKqM97fnM30BfSx8Yl0vhntCzkaB3N-sMznNr2mg11izyV1AeJtI4uPdpJsAZf-n3FihCrwXslBJc9oPFs2kMvaOJl3P8MCaerVzThNB2TXaaDMmYtaYpCd_LersUrCGEHmm2tJO9yhTrfpGOL01_B5-JsEPAGULVmuVeeX19UjzrIVFN_Kpq6QBYf_TXc45oyIejhrkLjhCdzn2LK2X4vMIS_YFvyOURR5FO5Ez6La-n3x_6ODgv9nkne61QMn5cIFgFuw11RoNk5sq3FQ34_UeBfgkGzyZaMuxnVxwoeHVGngPl4t47ooKJg) there is always an undefined error coming back and I have no clue how to debug or check what is the problem.

anyone who could give hints on what is going wrong here?

thanks!

Comment: Needs to be formated

Comment: what needs to be formated?

Comment: I get the following error when using your link: `com.google.apps.framework.request.ForbiddenException: User not allowed to save the pass.` I assume it's because I'm not a registered tester for your integration. What error do you get? I found the error by inspecting the error page (script tag)

Comment: Thanks @Noc, that's one step ahead. Couldn't find that error before. Yeah it is the same for me, although I am logged in with the same user as the app to my chrome

Comment: @Relicted where you able to figure this out? I am getting "Something went wrong. Please try again." Is there a place to see what the error is?

Comment: Check this issue on their github page: https://github.com/google-wallet/web-codelab/issues/2